# loadstart event not firing for InAppBrowser in phonegap 2.9

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing phonegap app where I need to open inAppBrowser (Which will display google login page).

For that I have written below code

```
$("#homePage").live("pageshow", function() {
    $("#btnLogin").click(function() {
        var ref = window.open(loginUrl, '_blank', 'location=yes');
        alert(ref); // It alerts 'window onject'
        ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {
            alert(event.url); // This alert is not firing
        });
    })
});
```

The browser window is displaying correctly (Without address bar in iPhone). But 'loadstart' event is not firing.

I am using phonegap 2.9 and generating app by build.phonegap.com

done below configuration setting in config.xml file

```
<!--     ios Setting for inAppBrowser -->
<plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
```

// For more info, I am using below JS files

```
< script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/phonegap-1.1.0.js" >< /script >
< script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js" >< /script >
< script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.js" >< /script >
```

Can anybody tell why loadstart event is not firing?

Comment: use jQuery 1.9 at least with jQM 1.4 and use `.on()` instead of `.live()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the issue,

According to phonegap [documentation](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/3.1.0/introduction_getting_started.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Build) we don't need to include the phonegap.js because during the build process, it will automatically include it. But declairation must required like

```
<script src="phonegap.js"></script>
```